# append into array value if it is inside quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Input array

```
var array = [
  'name',
  '"Mobile Number"',
  '"mobile1,mobile2"',
  'email2',
  'Address',
  'email21'
]

var matchkey = 'mobile1,mobile2'

res = res.map(function (value) {
if(value==matchkey){
return value+".string()"
}
else {
return value+".auto()"
}
            
        })
```

Current Output from above code

```
[
  'name.auto()',
  '"Mobile Number".auto()',
  '"mobile1,mobile2".auto()',
  'email2.auto()',
  'Address.auto()',
  'email21.auto()'
]
```

Expected Ouptput;

```
[
  'name',
  '"Mobile Number.auto()"',
  '"mobile1,mobile2.string()"',
  'email2.auto()',
  'Address.auto()',
  'email21.auto()'
]
```

Note: I don't want to remove double quote which is inside single quote because it is required for further processing

Answer (score 1):

Your matchkey doenst exist in your array.

String in array: '"mobile1,mobile2"'

MatchKey: 'mobile1,mobile2'

You must change your matchkey to:

```
var matchkey = '"mobile1,mobile2"'
```

Also, i don't understand your purpose, but if your expected Output is to have the name string without a function access, then you should add an else if statement:

```
if(value == matchkey){
    return value+".string()";
} else if(value == 'name') {
    return value;
} else {
    return value+".auto()";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```js
var array = [
  'name',
  '"Mobile Number"',
  '"mobile1,mobile2"',
  'email2',
  'Address',
  'email21'
]

var matchkey = '"mobile1,mobile2"'

const res = array.map(function(value) {
  return value == matchkey ? value.slice(0,-1) + ".string()\"" : 
    value.endsWith('"') ? value.slice(0,-1) + ".auto()" +'"' : value + ".auto()"
})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do the replacing:

```js
const result = array.map((element) =>
  element.replace(/^("?)(.*?)("?)$/, function () {
    return `${
      arguments[1]
    }${arguments[2] + (arguments[2] === matchkey ? '.string()' : '.auto()')}${arguments[3]}`;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change from `value==matchkey` to `value.includes(matchkey)` will be your desired output.

```js
var array = [
  "name",
  '"Mobile Number"',
  '"mobile1,mobile2"',
  "email2",
  "Address",
  "email21",
];

var matchkey = "mobile1,mobile2";

res = array.map(function (value) {
  if (value.includes(matchkey)) {
    return value + ".string()";
  } else {
    return value + ".auto()";
  }
});

console.log(res);
```